# Is it possible to pass a int and a string both from one activty to another , if yes then how to achive it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to send a string and a int type data from one activity to another but due to lack of knowledge i don't know how to do it.
With the particular coding given below  now i can only send any one of the data type.

searched a lot but not found any answer  appropriate for my question. If i have asked any thing wrong plzz notify me as i am new to android Dev.

Any help may be appreciated.

this is my java coding of the two activities :

***First.java***

```
public class QM extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qm);


}


public void FLG(View view) {

    // Do something in response to button
    EditText mEditText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     String str = mEditText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Q1.class);
     intent.putExtra("myExtra", str);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
}
```

***Second.java***

```
public class Q1 extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_q1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("myExtra")){                                
    TextView mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mText.setText("user name "+intent.getStringExtra("myExtra")+"!"); }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send 2 extras or even more as long you have different keys for it, so in your problem you need 2 extras one for String and one for Integer.

**sample:**

**pass:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Q1.class);
 intent.putExtra("myExtra", str);
 intent.putExtra("myExtraInt", yourInt);
```

**get:**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("myExtra") && intent.hasExtra("myExtraInt")){                                
   TextView mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   mText.setText("user name "+intent.getStringExtra("myExtra")+"!");
   int extraInt = intent.getIntExtra(myExtraInt);
}
```

Comment: @ Rod_algonquin really very thanxx for the help .. u have saved me from wasting some time ....!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give you some information.

Imagine the Intent's extras to be a (theoretically) infinitely sized bagpack. You can put certain type of data into it in an infinite number as long as each of the data has a unique name which is a string.
Internally it's a table that maps names to values.

So: Yes you can put String and Int simultaneously into the Intent's extras like this.

```
String str = "Test";
int val = 2933;
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("MyStringExtraUniqueName", str);
i.putExtra("MyIntExtraUniqueName", val);
```

To check for it use i.hasExtra("MyStringExtraUniqueName") as you did already and to get it use i.getExtra("MyStringExtraUniqueName").

BUT if you only use getExtra you'll be returned data of type `object`. Remember to cast the returned value to the appropriate type or use one of the specialized getter methods for some predefined data types.

See this for the available getters: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: thanxx fr sharing info...!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("intKey", 5);
    data.putString("stringKey", "stackoverflow");
    Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(data);

    //And in the second acitvity fetch this way
    Bundle data = getIntent().putExtras(b);
```